# Give an order for deleting vertices from a graph such that it doesn't disconnect the graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

This is a question from Algorithm Design by Steven Skiena (for interview prep):

An articulation vertex of a graph G is a vertex whose deletion disconnects G. Let G be a graph with n vertices and m edges. Give a simple O(n + m) that finds a deletion order for the n vertices such that no deletion disconnects the graph.

This is what I thought:

1. Run DFS on the graph and keep updating each node's oldest reachable ancestor (based on which we decide if it's a bridge cut node, parent cute node or root cut node)
2. If we find a leaf node(vertex) or a node which is not an articulation vertex delete it.
3. At the end of DFS, we'd be left with all those nodes in graph which were found to be articulation vertices

The graph will remain connected as the articulation vertices are intact. I've tried it on a couple of graphs and it seems to work but it feels too simple for the book.

Comment: Can't you just do a BFS and reverse the result? The removed nodes will then always be leaf nodes wrt. to the remaining BFS tree, so the graph stays connected.

Comment: or a post-order DFS would also work. As long as you have some spanning tree and you only remove leaves in this tree, the remaining graph stays connected.

Comment: @hammar, could you explain the post-order DFS idea?

Answer (score 1):

in 2 steps:

1. make the graph DAG using any traversal algorithm
2. do topology sort

each step finishes without going beyond O(m+n)

Comment: A top sort, will sort nodes from left to right or rather it gives us an order to process the vertices of the graph, it's not concerned about connectivity of the tree.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the graph is connected, then any random node reaches a subgraph whose spanning tree may be deleted in post-order without breaking the connectedness of the graph. Repeat in this manner until the graph is all gone.

Answer (score 1):

1. Utilize DFS to track the exit time of each vertex;
2. Delete vertices in the order of recorded exit time;

Answer (score -1):

If we always delete leaves of a tree one by one, rest of the tree remain connected. One particular way of doing this is to assign a pre-order number to each vertex as the graph is traversed using DFS or BFS. Sort the vertices in descending order (based on pre-order numbers). Remove vertices in that order from graph. Note that the leaves are always deleted first.